# Remembering loop variables after loop has ended in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def john():
    for i in range(5):
        if i == 3:
            break
    print(i)

john()
```

The function above prints 3 when called upon, whis is this so? Are loop variables still remembered after the loop has ended / break'ed'?

Comment: Yes, loop variable holds the last value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [For-loop variable scope](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002109.html)

> Previous proposals to make for-loop variables local to
>   the loop have stumbled on the problem of existing code
>   that relies on the loop variable keeping its value
>   after exiting the loop, and it seems that this is
>   regarded as a desirable feature.

If the sequence is empty, the variable does not get assigned to at all by the loop:

```
>>> for x in []:
        pass

>>> print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#66>", line 1, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```